# Xcode 7 Library not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I've updated to xcode 7 and when I run my project I got this error :

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/lp\276 \3411.dylib
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
>     Reason: image not found

and the `libsqlite3.dylib, libz.dlyb and libstdc++6.dlyb`are marked with red.

So I've removed those library and when I tried to link them again in this way :

1. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder)
   and type /usr/lib/
3. From /user/lib you can add : libz.dylib and more...

I didn't find the `libz.dlyb and libstdc++.6.dlyb`  in my **/usr/lib/** folder.

Please how to fix it ?

Comment: Linking to **PrivateFrameworks**... Do I need to say more?

Comment: @Macmade, yes can you explain more if don't mind, thanks ?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7.x, ***.dylib*** is changed to **.tdb**. Please check **libz.tdb**. Or you could just type in libz, it will pop out.